# Drop down not working in Top Navigation snippet

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, snippet

When I try to add top navigation snippet into my master page, the drop down functionality which works OOTB isn't working. The same you can see in the following screenshots:-

Case 1:-

[image: This is where it works without a custom master page]

Case 2 :-

[image: This is where it doesn't works using Snippet Gallery with a custom master page]

Any Help would be much appreciated as this is stopping me from setting permissions for various pages in my portal for different set of users.

Comment: Do you mean you have customize your master page? If so please include your code here.

Answer (score 0):

I found it how to do this! Actually earlier i were using system theme 'Oslo', so my structured navigation nodes were getting bonded to 'Oslo' i suppose. I had to remove all these nodes after adding my custom master page. Then after adding new Top Navigation snippet, i again added all the nodes again(created) and they started showing up in the dropdown accordingly.